# Rectangle over Tikzpicture with independent positioning

Tags: beamer, pgflayers

I think my problem is very simple, but yet I haven't found an apropriate solution.

I want to have a tikzpicture which will on the next slide be overlayed by some other content tikz content. For instance a rectangle so that the full picture can be made transparent and some text be added above it. However, I haven't found any solution how to overlay tikz content on the same slide without affecting the positioning of each other. I tried with using foreground

Putting them on different slides, positioning is independent:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[c]{Frame Titel}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \only<1>{
            \node[circle,minimum width=4cm,fill=red](a){};
            \node[left=-1cm of a.south west](SUST){Sustainability};
            \node[yshift=2cm,xshift=2cm,circle,minimum width=4cm,fill=green](b){};
            \node[right=-1cm of b.north east](PSY){Psychology};
            \node[yshift=-1cm,xshift=3cm,circle,minimum width=4cm,fill=blue](c){};
            \node[right=-1cm of c.south east](MARK){Marketing};
        }

        \only<2>
        {
            \begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
            \centering
            \node[rectangle,minimum width=\textwidth,minimum height=\textheight,fill=gray,opacity=0.8](node name){};

            \end{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
        }
        \end{tikzpicture}   
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

But when putting them on same slides, the background part moves:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[c]{Frame Titel}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \only<1->{
            \node[circle,minimum width=4cm,fill=red](a){};
            \node[left=-1cm of a.south west](SUST){Sustainability};
            \node[yshift=2cm,xshift=2cm,circle,minimum width=4cm,fill=green](b){};
            \node[right=-1cm of b.north east](PSY){Psychology};
            \node[yshift=-1cm,xshift=3cm,circle,minimum width=4cm,fill=blue](c){};
            \node[right=-1cm of c.south east](MARK){Marketing};
        }

        \only<2>
        {
            \begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
            \centering
            \node[rectangle,minimum width=\textwidth,minimum height=\textheight,fill=gray,opacity=0.8](node name){};

            \end{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
        }

        \end{tikzpicture}   
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome! There is a library dedicated to such situations, `overlay-beamer-styles`. It works by setting the opacity of object to zero on slides on which they should be hidden. Since you want to use `opacity=0.8`, you need to use the `alt` key. And you can place the rectangle at `(current bounding box.center)` to center it appropriately. So you want to use

```
\node[rectangle,minimum width=\textwidth,minimum height=\textheight,
    fill=gray,alt=<2->{opacity=0.8}{opacity=0}](node name) at (current
    bounding box.center){};
```

Note that `\centering` has no effect. Also the `foreground` layer is not needed but I keep it assuming you want to add more elements. I put both situations in the following example.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,overlay-beamer-styles}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[c]{Only visible on $<1>$}
\centering
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[visible on=<1>]
        \node(a){\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a.pdf}};
        \node[left=-1cm of a.south west](SUST){Sustainability};
        \node[yshift=2cm,xshift=2cm](b){\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-b.pdf}};
        \node[right=-1cm of b.north east](PSY){Psychology};
        \node[yshift=-1cm,xshift=3cm](c){\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-c}};
        \node[right=-1cm of c.south east](MARK){Marketing};
    \end{scope}

        \begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
        \node[rectangle,minimum width=\textwidth,minimum height=\textheight,
        fill=gray,alt=<2->{opacity=0.8}{opacity=0}](node name) at (current
        bounding box.center){};
        \end{pgfonlayer}{foreground}

 \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[c]{Visible on $<1-2>$}
\centering
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[visible on=<1-2>]
        \node(a){\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a.pdf}};
        \node[left=-1cm of a.south west](SUST){Sustainability};
        \node[yshift=2cm,xshift=2cm](b){\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-b.pdf}};
        \node[right=-1cm of b.north east](PSY){Psychology};
        \node[yshift=-1cm,xshift=3cm](c){\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-c}};
        \node[right=-1cm of c.south east](MARK){Marketing};
    \end{scope}

        \begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
        \centering
        \node[rectangle,minimum width=\textwidth,minimum height=\textheight,
        fill=gray,alt=<2->{opacity=0.8}{opacity=0}](node name) at (current
        bounding box.center){};
        \end{pgfonlayer}{foreground}

 \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Also with use of `overlay-beamer-styles`  and its macro `\alt{...}{...}` (as suggested @Schrödinger's cat in his answer) but without `\only<...>` and `pgfonlayer` as you have in your MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,
                overlay-beamer-styles}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame Titel}
    \centering
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=4cm}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
         inner sep = 0pt,
every label/.style = {label distance=-1mm, inner sep=2mm}
                            ]
\node[label=below left:Sustainability]      (a) {\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}; 
\node[label=above right:Psychology,
      above right=8mm and 0mm of a.center]  (b) {\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}; \node[label=below right:Marketing,
      below right=3mm and 9mm of a.center]  (c) {\includegraphics{example-image-duck}};
\fill[gray, 
      alt=<2->{fill opacity=0.8, text opacity=1}{fill opacity=0, text opacity=0}, % <---
      scale=1.2] 
      (current bounding box.south west) rectangle 
      (current bounding box.north east)
      node[midway, font=\huge, text=red] {some text};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: My answer does not use `\only`, so why do you highlight "without `\only`"? I also clearly mention why I left `pgfonlayer` in: the OP may want to add further stuff.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat ah, it seems that I was not clear here. I try to make comparison to OP MWE, not yours. I edit my answer and hopefully now is more clear.

Comment: Well, you adapted the most important ingredients of my answer: the `alt` key and the relative positioning using the `current bounding box` node, but give me credit for loading `overlay-beamer-styles` only.

Comment: Thank you so much! I appreciate how you help clueless Users like me! :)

Comment: @kilsen, you are welcome. Note, here is policy that instead or beside saying "thank you" you vote answer (by clicking up-triangle at top left side of answer) and then the one, which is the best suiting to you, accept (by clicking on check mark at top left side of answer). Happy TeX.ing!